# Xampp - How to find my ip address with version 8.1.6

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-workbench

I was watching this [YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlXM-fdqHPQ) of connecting xampp to mysqlworkbench. The only issue I'm having is that this video was uploaded last year 2021, which I'm assuming was a different version of xampp where the ip address was visibly there.

[image]

However, my version of xampp does not have that and the closest I got was going on the apache web server openconfig file and going above Listen to find some ip address, however, that is failing when I test the connection on mysqlworkbench. Either the ip address given to me is incorrect or something is wrong with mysqlworkbench.   [image]

I would like to know however where I can find my ip address with this current version of xampp.

Comment: What is your OS? You would not need xampp to find the IP, but a command line command can tell you.

Comment: @PaulT. It is a Mac Big Sur. I am also trying to find out the ip address of xampp, whatever that would be because it was easily visible on the youtube demo, but that was a different version I'm assuming, my version does not show me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the local host address which is: 127.0.0.1

You can also type: localhost in the URL bar of your browser.

You should see the XAMMP welcome screen. That information is coming from a folder that you can access from the main "Open Application Folder". Go to "htdocs" and that is where you will put all your webpage files.